# Como funciona o mega.nz?

Tags: base64

O Mega (sucessor do Megaupload) tem um jeito diferente e inovador dos demais site de downloads. Normalmente, sites de download envia o arquivo e o download é feito no navegador, mas no mega.nz baixa o base64 do arquivo e junta tudo no navegador. Alguém poderia explicar **detalhadamente** como isso funciona? Grato desde já

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [mega.co.nz](http://mega.co.nz) utiliza a [fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) (Apartir do google chrome 23, mas não restrita somente ao chrome) que basicamente escreve em uma seção restrita no seu sistema de arquivos local

> AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\

O que é **FileSystem API**: é uma solução de sistema de arquivos para a web. Os desenvolvedores podem armazenar grandes objetos em uma parte em área restrita do sistema de arquivos do usuário e ligar diretamente a eles através de URL. Embora Chrome e Opera são os únicos navegadores que atualmente implementam o recurso, sua padronização está em curso.
Fonte:

- [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/how-exactly-does-megas-download-work) (site da própria rede Stack Exchange)
- [Html5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/)